# Integer.parseInt sometimes has NumberFormatException

Tags: java, parseint

I have a program where a user enters a number (which will be an integer) into a `JTextField`. The program that uses `Integer.parseInt()` to get whatever is typed into the `JTextField`. Usually the program runs smoothly with no issues. However, every now and then I will get a `NumberFormatException` even among the same numbers. For instance, on one run of the program I could type in 5 into the `JTextField`. On another run I could do the same and type 5 into the `JTextField` and I would get a `NumberFormatException`. I didn't change the code or anything so I don't understand why this is happening. Here is a portion of the code:

```
JPanel an = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JLabel assignNamesLabel = new JLabel("Assign Book Names");
JLabel bookNumberLabel = new JLabel("Book Number");
JLabel nameOfBookLabel = new JLabel("Book Name");
final JTextField bookNumber = new JTextField(20);
final JTextField bookName = new JTextField(20);
JButton assignName = new JButton("Assign");

assignNamesLabel.setFont(f);
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
an.add(assignNamesLabel, gbc);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
an.add(bookNumberLabel, gbc);
gbc.gridx = 1;
an.add(bookNumber, gbc);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 2;
an.add(nameOfBookLabel, gbc);
gbc.gridx = 1;
an.add(bookName, gbc);
gbc.gridy = 3;
gbc.gridx = 1;
an.add(assignName, gbc);

assignNamesPanel.add(an, BorderLayout.CENTER);

tabs.addTab("Assign Book Names", assignNamesPanel);
// function
assignName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(bookNumber.getText());
        if (shelf.book[i] == null) {
            shelf.book[i] = new shelf();
        }
        shelf.book[i].bookName = bookName.getText();
        bookNumber.setText("");
        bookName.setText("");
        bookNumber.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

I get the error sometimes at:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(bookNumber.getText());
```

Comment: Make sure that the book number is only integers. Also, change it to this: `Integer.parseInt(bookNumber.getText().trim());` as there may be spaces.

Comment: If you get a `NumberFormatException` it is because the text in the field wasn't parsable as an `int`. For instance, it might have had a space in it, or have been completely empty. I suggest you catch the exception and print the string when it happens to see what the problem seems to be.

Comment: You question lacks sufficient details. Please add a use case and maybe a screenshot.

Comment: If you got a `NumberFormatException`, the input wasn't a number. Period. Whatever you may think. Re-examine your assumptions. If you get this exception, in this case you should just tell the user and make him retry.

Comment: Well, since this exception shows which String it tried to parse, you should know why it fails. And since you haven't posted such a stacktrace, we can just guess where the problem is.

Comment: The best solution is to try to prevent the user from entering bad data to begin with.  Search SO for how to restrict a JTextField to only accept digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add some logic to validate that it is a number before attempting to parse it. Since primitive integers cannot be null, a `-1` is returned. You can check so see if the processed value is valid as well. Of course, `-1` is only an example. If you need `-1` to be valid, just make the default `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or something.

Catching the error is the prefered way i.e. `parseIntSafelyWithCatch()`. You could also use an extraction method i.e. `parseIntSafelyWithExtraction()` as an alternative to avoid exception handling.

### NumberValidator

```
public class NumberValidator {
    public static final String INT_REGEX = "[^-?0-9]+";
    public static final String CONTAINS_INT_REGEX = "^.*[-?0-9]+.*$";

    public static int parseIntSafelyWithCatch(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value.trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static int parseIntSafelyWithExtraction(String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (value.matches(CONTAINS_INT_REGEX)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(value.replaceAll(INT_REGEX, ""));
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static boolean isValidNumber(int value) {
        return value != -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parseIntSafelyWithCatch("")); // -1
        System.out.println(parseIntSafelyWithCatch("42")); // 42
        System.out.println(parseIntSafelyWithCatch(" 42")); // 42
        System.out.println(parseIntSafelyWithCatch(" 42 ")); // 42
        System.out.println(parseIntSafelyWithCatch("-42")); // -42
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
int i = NumberValidator.parseIntSafelyWithCatch(bookNumber.getText());
boolean isValid = NumberValidator.isValidInteger(i);
```

Comment: Why? `Integer.parseInt()` already does the job. Just catch the exception. That way you're not writing extra code, and you're not running any risk of enforcing different rules from `parseInt()`.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks for the heads up. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String number = bookNumber.getText().trim();

if(!number.isEmpty())
{
// proceed
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The most likely problem is whitespace characters before or after the number. Change your code to this:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(bookNumber.getText().trim());
```